# How do you include hashtags within Twitter share link text?

Tags: twitter, hyperlink, share, hashtag

I'm writing a site with a custom tweet button that uses the **www.twitter.com/share** function, however the problem I am having is including hash '#' characters within the tweet text.

For example:

http://www.twitter.com/share?url=www.example.com&text=I+am+eating+#branstonpickel+right+now

The tweet text comes out as '**I am eating**' and omits the hash and everything after.

I had a quick look on the Twitter forums and learnt the hash '#' character cannot be part of the share url.
 On https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/512#comment-877 it was said that:

> Hashes are special characters in the URL (they identify document fragments) so they, and anything following, does not get sent the server.

and

> you need to URLEncode it, so use %23

When I tried the 2nd point in my test link:

www.twitter.com/share?url=www.example.com&text=I+am+eating+%23branstonpickel+right+now

The tweet text came out as '**I am eating %23branstonpickel right now**' literally including %23 instead of converting it to a hash.

Sorry for the waffely question, but does anyone know what it is I'm doing wrong?
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It looks like this is the basic setup:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
url=<url to tweet>
text=<text to tweet>
hashtags=<comma separated list of hashtags, with no # on them>
```

This would pre-built a tweet of: `<text> <url> <hashtags>`

The above example would be:
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.example.com&text=I+am+eating+branston+pickel+right+now&hashtags=bransonpickel,pickles

There used to be a bug with the hashtags parameter... it only showed the first n-1 hashtags. Currently this is fixed.

Comment: Appears the "n-1" bug has been fixed by now

Answer (score 59):

you can use %23 instead of hash (#) in url eg

http://www.twitter.com/share?url=www.example.com&text=I+am+eating+%23branston+%23pickel+right+now

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but i think the hashtag has to be passed as a separate variable that will appear at the end of your tweet ie:

http://www.twitter.com/share?url=www.example.com&text=I+am+eating+branston+pickel+right+now&hashtag=bransonpickel

will result in "I am eating branston pickel right now #branstonpickle"

On a separate note, I think pickel should be pickle!

Cheers

Toby

Comment: It did 11 months ago! The intent api has now been further formalised to work like so: http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=I+am+eating+branston+pickel+right+now&url=www.example.com&hashtags=branstonpickel

Comment: and branson should be branston :)

Comment: The original question was about having a # character as part of a long URL. The option you mention is for adding twitter #hashtags.

Comment: Wow, three year old question! And nope, the question was asking how to tweet with an inline #hashtag (namely: I am eating #branstonpickel right now).

Answer (score 3):

use encodeURIComponent to encode the url

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP, you can use the following:

```
<?php echo 'http://www.twitter.com/share?' . http_build_query(array(
    'url' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'text' => 'I am eating #branstonpickel right now'
)); ?>
```

This will do all the URL encoding for you, and it's easy to read.

For more information on the http_build_query, see the PHP manual:
https://www.php.net/http_build_query

Answer (score 0):

For url with `line jump`, `#` , `@` and special unicode in it, the following works :

```
var lineJump = encodeURI(String.fromCharCode(10)),
hash = "%23", arobase="%40",
tweetText = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Le signe chinois '+hans+' '+item.pinyin+': '+item.definition.replace(";",",")+'.'
    +lineJump+'Merci '+arobase+'Inalco_Officiel '+arobase+'CRIparis ❤️ '
    +lineJump+hash+'Chinois '+hash+'MOOC'
    +lineJump+'https://hanzi.cri-paris.org/',
tweetTxtUrlEncoded = tweetText+ "" +encodeURIComponent('#'+lesson+encodeURIComponent(hans));
```

Answer (score 0):

**urlencode**

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?= urlencode("I am eating #branstonpickel right now"); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this code and modify it

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello%20this%20%23hashtag"> </a>
```

20% means space
23% means hashtag

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can easily encode the special characters using [`encoreURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

(Warning: don't use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) as "#" and "@" are not escaped.)

Here's an example with mention and hashtag:

```js
const text = "Hello #world ! Go follow @StackOverflow";
const tweetUrl = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${ encodeURIComponent(text) }`;
```