# Name Game Social Share

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, share, generator

I am working on a Name Game type of Name Generator where you enter some fields and associated variables are pulled. I have the generator working and the share links working, however I can't get them to populate with the final 'sillyname' variable. 
AKA When you click share, it has a generic message but I am trying to get it to dynamically enter the name into the tweet or facebook share text.

Any help on this would be awesome.

Here is the link for you to dig deeper.
http://codepen.io/drewlandon/pen/VLvpjq

I have this in the twitter/facebook share function:

```
    var twitterWindow = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://sweetleafmarijuana.com/&amp;text=My Sweet and Fierce Name... &amp;via=TheSweetestLeaf &amp;hashtags=SweetFierceName', 'twitter-popup', 'height=350,width=600'); if(twitterWindow.focus) { twitterWindow.focus(); }
return false; } var facebookShare = document.querySelector('[data-js="facebook-share"]');
```

However I found this and feel like it needs to be something along these lines:

```
    function twitterShare(){
    var shareText='My funny pseudonym is '+accents_to_regulars(outputName)+', according to @...'
```

So i'm thinking i need something like this (but having trouble from there)

```
    var twitterMessage = "My #SWEETFIERCENAME is " + hungryName + ", according to @thesweetestleaf's #SweetFierceName Name Generator";
    var facebookMessage = "My name is " + hungryName + "";
```

Comment: I don't see a `sillyname` variable.

Comment: Heres the non-codepen one I'm working on http://www.sweetleafmarijuana.com/wp-content/uploads/sweetfiercename/

Comment: Also i was grabbing the two examples from http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/low_concept/2013/07/carlos_danger_name_generator_use_our_widget_to_get_a_name_like_anthony_weiner.html and http://codepen.io/drewlandon/pen/pJJPqX

Comment: the id of the content that is being created is id="msgField"

Comment: I don't get your problem.  If you have what you want in `twitterMessage` as you suggest, why not just append it in place of the existing message (i.e. after `;text='+twitterMessage`?

Comment: Prefilling the Facebook message is not allowed. The user have to type every single character

Comment: So then for twitter, let me back WAY up.  I have the name generator (http://www.sweetleafmarijuana.com/wp-content/uploads/sweetfiercename/), i have it set up to social share with the twitter share button however it is just static text. I would like to fill in the tweet with the results of their name.  I found a few working examples and see sort of how others are making it work but I'm having trouble applying that to mine. Sorry, kinda a js newb still. @JamesWilkins

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the text for the URL.

It works here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kpdvqa

```
twitterShare.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var twitterWindow = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://sweetleafmarijuana.com/&amp;text='+encodeURIComponent(getSillyName())+'&amp;via=TheSweetestLeaf &amp;hashtags=SweetFierceName', 'twitter-popup', 'height=350,width=600');
    if(twitterWindow.focus) { twitterWindow.focus(); }
        return false;
}
```

The `#` character has special meaning in URLs.

As for the Facebook message, there is no way to pre-fill that anymore:
http://www.quora.com/With-Facebooks-share-link-is-there-a-way-to-prefill-the-text-to-be-posted

You will have to take a closer look at the FB [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3) to see other options, like perhaps updating the `caption` property instead.

Comment: That works great! Thank you! I also need to style out the results. When I put any <div>'s or <span>'s in the variable return fields, the tweet pulls them and actually spells them out as "<div>". Is there a way I can style out the results with a span or a couple classes and it won't get pulled by the twitter share?

Comment: The escaped characters should be arriving unescaped when processed on the receiving end. It's up to twitter to handle this - are you sure it's possible to do that?  I don't think that's allowed.

Comment: FYI: I think I found a similar post here that might help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127808/how-do-you-include-hashtags-within-twitter-share-link-text